# AngularJS ng-click function that adds class to clicked navigation link

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm struggling to find the correct code to a navigation sidebar on a angularJS app. What should happen is when you click a link a background color should highlight the active link. It does work as expected except you have to click each link twice before the highlight shows.
What is it that I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

javascript

```
 $scope.addActiveClass = function ($index) {
        $scope.addActiveClass = $index;
        var checked = $('ul.sidebar2-nav li');

        $(checked).on("click", "", function () {
            $(this).addClass('active-label');

        });
     }
```

html

```
<nav id="program-editor-pullout" menustate="closed" >
        <ul class="list-unstyled sidebar2-nav">
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: home}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".home">Home</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: evaluations}" ui-sref-active="active"  ui-sref=".evaluation">Evaluations</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: questions}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".question">Questions</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass()" ng-class="{active: hstranscripts}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".hstranscripts">High School Transcripts</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: collegetranscripts}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".collegetranscripts">College Transcripts &amp; Course Work</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: prerequisites}" ui-sref-active="active"  ui-sref=".prerequisites">Prerequisites</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active-label">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                        <a ng-click="addActiveClass($index)" ng-class="{active: documents}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".document">Documents</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
  ul.sidebar2-nav li a.active {
   color: #000;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
  ul.sidebar2-nav li.active-label {
   background: whitesmoke;
  }
```

Comment: You are waiting for first click for binding click events on all li.. so on first click it will bind event.. and in next event it will fire that event.. thats why it taking two click for class apply

Comment: What would be the solution to have the active class binded on first click?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Your example was correct, but in my html code I had this:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active-label" ng-click="addActiveClass($event, $index)">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                <a ng-class="{active: home}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".home">Home</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Notice how the anchor tag has the ng-class and the ui-sref-active on it. I removed these attributes and it works as expected. Thank you for your guidance, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score -1):

Move click event from a to parent li tag

```
<nav id="program-editor-pullout" menustate="closed" >
            <ul class="list-unstyled sidebar2-nav">
                <li ui-sref-active="active-label" ng-click="addActiveClass($event, $index)">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="true">
                            <a ng-class="{active: home}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".home">Home</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Change your click handler to something like this

```
$scope.addActiveClass = function ($event, $index) {
        $scope.addActiveClass = $index;
        //var checked = $('ul.sidebar2-nav li');

        //$(checked).on("click", "", function () {
        //    $(this).addClass('active-label');

        //});

        $($event.target).addClass('active-label');
     }
```

Comment: I've added this new code, but the click event isn't adding the active-label class to the li elememt

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something?

Comment: I found the solution and posted it above, thank you for your help. The problem was I had ng-class and ui-sref-active in the anchor tags. Once I removed these and had the ui-sref-active only placed on the li tag it all worked as it should